# SQLiteException: near "between": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UnitConversion.db";

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                DatabaseContract.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UNIT_FROM + " TEXT," +
                DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UNIT_CONVERTING_TO + " TEXT," +
                DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_Ratio + " TEXT)";
```

this is the error code:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "between": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Conversions between units (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Converting from unit TEXT,Converting to unit TEXT,Ratio TEXT)
```

can't figure out what I've done wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table name has spaces `Conversions between units` (or you should update DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME).

You probably wanted to name it something like `conversions_between_units` but if the table name really has spaces in it it should be between single or double quotes:

```
"CREATE TABLE \"" + DatabaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + "\" ("
```

even though single quotes are supported by SQLite, but the portable way is to use double quotes.

The same goes for *COLUMN_NAME_UNIT_FROM* and *COLUMN_NAME_UNIT_CONVERTING_TO* which also contain spaces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207176/discussion-on-answer-by-jeprubio-sqliteexception-near-between-syntax-error).